# No funcionan las opciones de selección de archivo en el sublime-build

Tags: sublimetext3, build

Estoy realizando un archivo de compilación por defecto para mis archivos markdown. El problema es que cuando coloco las opciones de selección en `sublime-build` no me las reconoce para identificar en que archivo estoy actualmente y por lo tanto no se ejecuta build.

Cuando sacó las opciones de selección de archivo se ejecuta normalmente, pero tengo que escogerlo de un menu de builds, cosa que no quiero.

Quiero que únicamente cuando presione `ctrl+b` se ejecute la build correspondiente al archivo que estoy editando.

Esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo `markdown.sublime-build`

```
{
    "cmd": ["pandoc", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name.pdf"],
    "selector": "source.markdown, source.md",
    // "selector": "source.markdown",
    // "selector": "source.md",
    // "target": "my_example_build",
    // "file_patterns": ["*.md"],
    // "keyfiles": ["Markdown", "markdown"],
}
```

Todas las opciones comentadas ya las he intentado y ninguna a funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

Para el atajo `Ctrl+B` tendrias  que incluir esta linea en la siguiente entrada de tu archivo `"Key  Bindings - User"`.:

```
 { "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "build" }
```

Comment: esa entrada ya se encuentra por defecto en sublime text, el mensaje que me aparece al presionarla es `No Build System`.